# Adding a li dynamik in a ul menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that is already loaded by jquery. I dont want to edit the current js file tha loads this menu so i want with jquery to add an extra li at the end of the last li in this menu. My menu structure is:

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <ul id="dcsns-filter" class="option-set filter">
        <li><a href="#filter" data-group="dc-filter" data-filter="*" class="selected link-all">all</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried the code below without chance..

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tsource = "http://www.google.com"
    $(".dcsns-toolbar").find("li:last").after("<div style='width:100px; height:61px; float: left; top:0; position: absolute; margin-top:140px; margin-right:5px;'><div style=' width:65px; height:61px; float:left;'>Πηγή: <a href='" + tsource + "' target='_blank' style='color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px;'>Google</a></div></div>");
});
</script>
```

Thank you!!

Comment: In your example you don't have an element with the class `.dcsns-toolbar`.

Comment: Plus, you should append only `<li>`s to an `<ul>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I beleive you have an error in your jQuery Selector:

```
$(".dcsns-toolbar")  // <--- This element doesn't exist
```

should be

```
$('#dcsns-filter')
```

and then jQuery will find your element and you can append to that.

```
$('#dcsns-filter').find("li:last").after("<div style='width:100px; height:61px; float: left; top:0; position: absolute; margin-top:140px; margin-right:5px;'><div style=' width:65px; height:61px; float:left;'>Πηγή: <a href='" + tsource + "' target='_blank' style='color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px;'>Google</a></div></div>");
```

Comment: Dear @mark i added this code: $('#dcsns-filter').find("li:last").after("<div style='width:100px; height:61px; float:left; background-color:#000;'></div>");

Without Luck.. if i do inspect element an put the div after the last li it works but it doesn't load it with Jquery.

Comment: @IreneT. What doesn't load? If there were events bound to those elements, and you create a new element, you will need to rebind the event selector to include the new element.

Answer (score 1):

```
var innerHtml = '<div>...</div>';
var newListItem = $('<li />').html(innerHtml);
$("#dcsns-filter").append(newListItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dcsns-filter").append('Your new li html');
```

Comment: You should probably format `Your new li html` like a new list element html